Как подружить ValidationBehavior и LoggingBehavior в MediatR?
Прежде чем выполнить код в Handler, у меня есть два конвейера поведений:
LoggingBehavior
public class LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : class
    where TResponse : class
{
    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request,
        RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        Serilog.Log.Information("Начало");

        TResponse result = await next();

        Serilog.Log.Information("Конец");

        return result;
    }
}

ValidationBehavior
public class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
    where TResponse : class
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

    public ValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(
        TRequest request, 
        RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if(!_validators.Any())
        {
            return await next();
        }

        var errors = _validators
            .Select(validator => validator.Validate(request).ToString(";"))
            .Where(errors => errors != "")
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

        if(errors.Any())
        {
            return new ObjectResult(errors) 
            {
                StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
            } as TResponse;
        }
        else
        {
            return await next();
        }
    }
}

Вот порядок их регистрации
builder.Services.AddScoped(
    typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>),
    typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>));

builder.Services.AddScoped(
    typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>),
    typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));

При пройденной валидации идёт логирование, но при неудачно я возвращаю ошибку и дальше никуда не перехожу. Есть ли способ подружить эти конвейера, чтобы при неудачно валидации всё-равно было логирование но при этом код в Handler не выполнялся?
Я думал над созданием класс Result в котором будет свойство пройдена ли валидация, но тогда это свойство нужно будет проверять в Handler и это будет выглядеть как костыль.
